# Intel QuickSync on OSX

Tags: macos, encoding

Are there any Encoder on OSX that takes advantage of Intel QuickSync? Its Hardware Accelerated H.264 Encoder built into Intel CPU.

Obviously Apple has been using it themselves for AirPlay. But from What i remembered ( 2013 ) Intel never had an SDK on OSX, and Apple never opened up an API. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Apple Compressor](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/compressor/id424390742?mt=12), it's automatic, depending on your machine & settings.

Hardware acceleration is enabled automatically within Compressor. If your system has the right set of chips, and you select the right compression setting, hardware encoding kicks in.

- Hardware encoding is available on all shipping Macs that use an i5 or i7, Sandy Bridge or Ivy Bridge processor; except the new Mac Pro.
- Hardware encoding is applied to QuickTime and MPEG-4 compression that uses the H.264 codec; but not to Blu-ray Disc compression.
- Hardware encoding cannot be used for multi-pass encoding. In fact, turning on multi-pass encoding turns off hardware encoding.

Source & for further analysis : [Compressor 4.1: Hardware Acceleration](https://larryjordan.com/articles/compressor-4-1-hardware-acceleration/)

Comment: Thanks, are there anythings that is free? Why has Apple kept it all to themselves?

Comment: The API is public, it just needs someone to write for it - try http://sourceforge.net/projects/qstranscode/?source=directory

Comment: I think Qstranscode only works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MacX Videoconverter Pro from the App Store and it has an Quicksync option, which really makes it much faster and does consume less CPU power, so the MBA 13 i7 is still usable well while converting